# Cannot get value from a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, converters

What i want to do is to get the value of the total price textbox from the codes below and declare it afterwards:

```
private void UpdateTotalBill()
    {
        decimal vat = 0;
        decimal TotalPrice = 0;
        long TotalProducts = 0;
        foreach (DataListItem item in dlCartProducts.Items)
        {
            Label PriceLabel = item.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label; // get price 
            TextBox ProductQuantity = item.FindControl("txtProductQuantity") as TextBox; // get quantity

            Int64 priceLabel, productQuantity;
            bool conversionResult = Int64.TryParse(PriceLabel.Text, out priceLabel);
            if (!conversionResult) continue;
            conversionResult = Int64.TryParse(ProductQuantity.Text, out productQuantity);
            if (!conversionResult) continue;
            decimal ProductPrice = priceLabel * productQuantity; //computation fro product price. price * quantity
            vat = (TotalPrice + ProductPrice) * 0.12M; // computation for vat
            vat = Math.Round(vat, 2);
            TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ProductPrice;
            TotalProducts = TotalProducts + productQuantity;
        }
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(vat);
        txtTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice + 40.0M + vat); // add vat + 40 delivery charge to total price
        txtTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalProducts);
    }
```

and be read by the "decimal amount = ?":

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String paymentSwitchUrl = "http://test.dragonpay.ph/Pay.aspx";
        String merchantId = "****";
        String secretKey = "****"; // Application["secretKey"].ToString();
        String txnId = "003";
        decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPrice);
        String ccy = "PHP";
        String description = "any description";
        String email = "paolodexter@yahoo.com";

        String message = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}:{6}",  
            merchantId, txnId, amount.ToString("#0.00"), ccy, description, email,
            secretKey);
        String digest = GetSHA1Digest(message); 

        String redirectString = 
        String.Format("{0}?merchantid={1}&txnid={2}&amount={3}&ccy={4}&" + 
            "description={5}&email={6}&digest={7}&message={8}", 
            paymentSwitchUrl, 
            merchantId,
            txnId, 
            amount.ToString("#0.00"), 
            ccy, 
            Server.UrlEncode(description),
            Server.UrlEncode(email), 
            digest,
            message); 

        // send browser to Payment Switch 
        Response.Redirect(redirectString, true);
    }
```

i tried this line of code:

```
decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPrice);
```

but it gives me an error saying :

```
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to convert the textbox component, and not the text it contains, to a `decimal`. A simple change will fix this:

```
decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPrice.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

> decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPrice);

this line is actually trying to convert Textbox control to decimal

you need to use the "**Text**" property as you did during the page load. 
Also, it is advisable to always use TryParse() instead of explicit convertion to handle runtime conversion errors.

> > decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out decimal_val);

Comment: its just a variable name I mentioned for example.